# Best Practices Passing In A Limited Amount Of Variable Values Into Method

Tags: php

I am creating a class for Contact management and I am curious if anyone has any creative ideas to pass in options to make certain columns sortable via `ORDER BY` in MySQL.

There are 5 columns.  ID, Firstname, Lasname, Phone Number, Email.

All of these will need to be sortable Ascending and Descending.  The obvious answer would just be to pass in a string for instance "firstname DESC" -- but seems a little to open and would like to make the class a little more restrictive.

Any ideas?

Comment: sounds like something that should be ideally done client side with js, much faster than retrieving all the data every time.

Comment: That's not possible.  The data sets will be entirely to large.  The order by needs to be part of the MySQL query.

Comment: how large? i do this with 60k rows table, pagination is part of the js to. but otherwise just turn the headers in to links and pass the var in the url

Comment: It could potentially be in the millions of rows.  Regardless even 60k is way to much.  I can't depend on our customers browsers potentially not handling it.  It has to be done server side.

Comment: ok that's fine, now you know to qualify future questions :-0

Comment: @Dagon Actually, nobody was thinking about doing this client-side until you mentioned it... :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type-safest method would be to use an object which can only hold certain values:

```
function getUser(UserSortOption $sortOrder) {
    ...
    $sql .= $sortOrder->getField() . $sortOrder->getDirection();
    ...
}

getUser(new UserSortOption(UserSortOption::FIRSTNAME, UserSortOption::DESC));
```

Gets you all the advantages of strict typing and enumerations. Can be a little bit of an overkill though to have to define, test and include a separate class for every function argument.

Otherwise, you'll have to check inside the function:

```
function getUser(array $sort) {
    $sortField = key($sort);
    $sortDirection = current($sort);

    if (!in_array($sortField, array('Firstname', ...))) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException("Invalid value $sortField for sort parameter");
    }

    ...
}

getUser(array('Firstname' => 'desc'));
```

Comment: Thanks, option 2 looks like what we'll go with.